# Two table names are the same if the system is case-insensitive

Tags: mysql, windows, import, wamp, case-insensitive

So, I have been developing a project for a while. Up until now I have been working under `Windows 7` using `VirtualBox`, using a virtual `Linux` server. Now I would like to work under a `Windows 8` machine without the pain of assigning memory to a Virtual `Linux` machine.

The project uses a `MySQL` database and I exported it and then tried to import it into my `Windows` environment. Apparently some old tables were created with the names of `Message` and `message`, respectively. This did not cause any problems in my virtual `Linux` server nor on the live `Linux` server, as the table names were case-sensitive, therefore it was perfectly valid to have two similar names for the tables, namely `Message` and `message`. However, under `Windows 8`, using `wamp`, I cannot import the database.

I have been trying to set up a value in `my.ini` as follows:

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

however, when I tried to import the database again, my try did not succeed, as the table name of `Message` seemed to be in conflict with the table name of `message` yet again. I expected that the setting would allow me to create two tables, one with the name of `Message` and another with the name of `message`. However, the setting did not help at all (yes, I have restarted `mysql` service and the `wamp` alltogether, but no luck, I simply cannot import the database). I have also checked whether the setting of `lower_case_table_names=2` was applied and yes, it was applied. However, still, I cannot create the `Message` and the `message` tables in the database. In the symphony of my total desperation I have tried the setting of

```
lower_case_table_names=0
```

as well, but no luck either.

So, it is either me, or this setting is not working (however, it was marked to be the solution in many similar questions). `MySQL Server version is 5.5.24`.

So, the question is: **can I resolve in the MySQL server used by wamp to import a database having table names, such as message and Message and if so, how?**

If there is no solution working (at least at my end) I will have to consider two possible solutions:

1. Install `VirtualBox` (sigh) on my new laptop and work on this computer in the same style as on my old one.
2. Modify the name of one of the tables in the database and modify all its references in the project, deploy it and THEN to export and import the database, without having both the `Message` and the `message` table.

I know it was not wise to create the message and the Message tables in the same database, but I inherited the project this way. I have two alternative solutions if there is no easy-peasy solution, but I am really interested if there is an easy solution of modifying a setting.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by:

1. Creating a table called Messages
2. Inserting all the records found in Message into Messages
3. Dropping Message
4. Modifying all the references to Message so that they reference now on Messages

If anybody encounters this problem, don't wait for answers, I have been waiting for 14 hours, so you will lose your time as well. Instead, bite the bullet and use my idea, or use a virtual Linux machine to solve your issue.